# How to set input field value when check box is checked using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need when i will be checked the check box the respective input field will have the required value. Let me show my code below.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors"> Five
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors"> Ten
</label>
<input type="text" name="color" id="clr" ng-model="color" readonly />
```

I need here when user will check the `Five` the input field will get `5` and when user will check `Ten`,the input field value will be `10`.

Comment: so then are these supposed to be radio buttons rather than checkboxes? what happens if *both* `Five` and `Ten` are checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought maybe you meant to use radio instead of check boxes (since the color can be either 5 OR 10).
here's a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ngy2NF4qVbISy1Xw5sF?p=preview).

and the code:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.color" value="5"> Five
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="data.color" value="10"> Ten
</label>
<input type="text" name="color" id="clr" ng-model="data.color" readonly />
```

js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { color: '' };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use **[`ng-true-value=""`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)** in checkbox

Like this

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color" ng-true-value="5" ng-false-value="0" name="favoriteColors"> Five
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color" ng-true-value="10" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="color" name="favoriteColors"> Ten
</label>
<input type="text" name="color" id="clr" ng-model="color" readonly />
```

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/5s1bfjco/8/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="color=5" name="favoriteColors"> Five
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="color=10" name="favoriteColors"> Ten
</label>
<input type="text" name="color" id="clr" ng-model="color" readonly />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5s1bfjco/7/

Comment: glad to see that you use my fiddle :P

Answer (score 0):

Bind your checkbox inputs to `ng-model` as well, and then assign the value accordingly. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked.five"> Five
<input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked.ten"> Ten
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.isChecked = {};
if ($scope.isChecked.five) {
  $scope.color = 5;
}
if ($scope.isChecked.ten) {
  $scope.color = 10;
}
```

It should automatically update your input value as you check/uncheck the checkboxes, due to two-way binding.